# GRPC-gateway default healthCheck support

Tags: grpc

I'm using gRPC-gateway that works perfectly fine. But I need to have HealthCheck. I enabled DefaultHealthCheck and it works perfectly. TO make it possible, to check state over HTTP1.1 I found this solution https://github.com/salrashid123/grpc_health_proxy. ANd it works as well. But it's not the best solution to maintain 2 "gateways" + server by it self. So, my qestion is - if there is possible to enable defaultHealthCheck proxying in gRPC gateway?
BEcause I don't understand how to implement this solution from docs
https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/operations/health_check/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the easiest way is to implement HealthCheck protocol procedures that basically return healthy state(200) and regenerate stubs with it, also gateway should be generated with it. Works perfectly fine for ALB AWS.